# Android how to handle app crashing when cyber-roam disconnected

Tags: android, json, internet-connection

I am using volley jar to get data from web-service. As my WiFi- connection having Cyber-roam setting. Whenever cyber-roam is connected with mobile all are working good, as soon as cyber-roam disconnected after sometime, app crashes while calling web-service.

I am getting following response -

```html
<HTML><HEAD>
<meta http-equiv=pragma content=nocache>
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Expires CONTENT=-1>
<SCRIPT>
location.href="http://172.16.16.16:8090/httpclient.html"
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD><BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am also using BroadcastReceiver to check internet is connected or not. But it not help me.
It only showing toast message when, Wifi or mobile data on/off. Help me and Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should include stacktrace..

Comment: Please post a logcat and/or some code that is causing the issue

Comment: Here is link to see logcat output. https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rqs4qtv671ydu6/error?dl=0

Comment: boolean isConnected = arg1.getBooleanExtra(
    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
  if (isConnected) {
   Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connection Lost",
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } else {
   Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
     .show();
  }